# Unreliable shared memory circular buffer with read-only consumer

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

This code is slightly platform dependent but should be pretty easy to port. The goal with this code was to create a circular buffer where the consumer could be limited to read-only access of the buffer (the test uses threads but it could be ported to processes fairly easily.)

I think I probably made at least one mistake in this code and I'm not even sure it is technically possible to implement in a standards compliant way.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <xmmintrin.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 64U
#define PACKET_SIZE 128U

#define CUTOFF 2147483648U

typedef uint32_t seqno;

struct packet_header {
        seqno production_count;
};

struct packet_payload {
        char bytes[PACKET_SIZE - sizeof (struct packet_header)];
};

union packet {
        struct {
                struct packet_header header;
                struct packet_payload payload;
        } format;
        char bytes[PACKET_SIZE];
};

static union packet volatile buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {{.format.header.production_count = -1}};

static void *producer(void *foo)
{
        seqno producer_count = 0U;

        for (;;) {
                uint64_t payload_number = random();

                struct packet_payload payload = {0};
                memcpy(payload.bytes, &payload_number, sizeof payload_number);

                __atomic_store_n(&buffer[producer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.header.production_count, -1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

                /* This store needs to be SEQ_CST to prevent the write moving before it (whether via the compiler or the CPU */


                buffer[producer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.payload = payload;

                __atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_RELEASE);

                __atomic_store_n(&buffer[producer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.header.production_count, producer_count, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);

#if defined LOG
                fprintf(stdout, "production count: %u, payload: %lu, produced\n", producer_count, payload_number);
#endif

                producer_count = (producer_count + 1U) % CUTOFF;
        }
}

static void *consumer(void *foo)
{
        seqno consumer_count = 0U;

        for (;;) {
                seqno count = __atomic_load_n(&buffer[consumer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.header.production_count, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);

                if ((seqno)-1 == count) {
                        /* the message hasn't been completed yet */
                        _mm_pause();
                        continue;
                }

                __atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);

                struct packet_payload payload = buffer[consumer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.payload;

                /* Note that the double check needs to be SEQ_CST to prevent the read moving after it (whether via the compiler or the CPU */

                if (count != __atomic_load_n(&buffer[consumer_count % BUFFER_SIZE].format.header.production_count, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)) {
                        /* torn read, skip packet */
                        consumer_count = (count + 1U) % CUTOFF;
                        continue;
                }

                if (consumer_count > count) {
                        /* we have incremented the consumer count enough to catch up to the producer */
                        _mm_pause();
                        continue;
                }

                uint64_t payload_number;
                memcpy(&payload_number, payload.bytes, sizeof payload_number);

#if defined LOG
                fprintf(stderr, "production count: %u, payload: %lu, consumed\n", count, payload_number);
#endif

                consumer_count = (count + 1U) % CUTOFF;
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        pthread_t xx;
        pthread_create(&xx, 0, producer, 0);
        pthread_create(&xx, 0, consumer, 0);

        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The producer can outstrip the consumer very easily. You are going to need *some* feedback from the consumer to the producer to avoid overproduction (or just avoiding overwriting the packet the consumer is currently reading).

Comment: @ratchetfreak Correct. Unread packets are simply dropped. This is an unreliable transport like UDP.

Comment: You still have the danger of the producer writing to the packet while the consumer is reading leading to (at least) corrupt data (it's undefined behavior so nasal demons can happen)

Comment: @ratchetfreak Do note that there is a double check of the `production_count` to look for possibly torn reads. But yes, technically this is undefined behaviour. I wish there was a way to get around that but I don't think its possible without giving up the desirable property of a read only consumer.

Answer (score 1):

## Merge cases

In the consumer, you have two separate checks:

> ```
>             if ((seqno)-1 == count) {
>                     /* the message hasn't been completed yet */
>                     _mm_pause();
>                     continue;
>             }
> ```

and later:

> ```
>             if (consumer_count > count) {
>                     /* we have incremented the consumer count enough to catch up to the producer */
>                     _mm_pause();
>                     continue;
>             }
> ```

Since `consumer_count` doesn't change in between those two blocks of code, you could move the second check up and merge it with the first one:

```
            if ((seqno)-1 == count || consumer_count > count) {
                    /* the message hasn't been completed yet, or we have */
                    /* incremented the consumer count enough to catch up to the producer */
                    _mm_pause();
                    continue;
            }
```

Moving the second check up could actually help you avoid dropping a packet that didn't need to be dropped.